# I have a sample table with distinct departments now the scenario is,need to display the highest repeated departments in a table with all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

INPUT:

```
empid department  names    salary
----------------------------------
1   dotnet      klrahul      1000
2   dotnet      dhawan       2000
3   dotnet      virat        1500
4   design      dhoni        3000
5   design      karthik      2000
6   design      phant        3040
7   php         chawal       4000
8   php         kpandya      2000
9   php         skaual       4300
10  php         bhumra       2000
11  dotnet      vijay        1646
```

OUTPUT:

```
empid   department  names   salary
----------------------------------
1   dotnet      klrahul      1000
2   dotnet      dhawan       2000
3   dotnet      virat        1500
11  dotnet      vijay        1646
7   php         chawal       4000
8   php         kpandya      2000
9   php         skaual       4300
10  php         bhumra       2000
```

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question. What are you asking here? What have you tried so far to answer it? Also, try to keep your subject succinct; what you've written there should likely be in your question (along with your question).

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanna todo :) ///...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by dept) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
order by rank() over (order by cnt desc), dept;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
SELECT emp_id, dept,count(*) OVER (PARTITION by dept)
FROM table
ORDER BY count(*) OVER (PARTITION by dept) desc, 
emp_id
```